# Change source in frame from an external link

Tags: iframe

Okay Internet, got a doosy here.

Let me try to explain this the best I can.

I have a website, and on one of its page it has an iframe.

the link to this website is www.mywebsite.com/content.html

Here's what i need to do:
I need to create a link to www.mywebsite.com/content.html but change the source in the side the iframe. I've read some things on stackoverflow but they didn't help explain what i need to do.

Help?

Comment: Are you the publisher of content.html at www.mywebsite.com or are you talking about serving up content from www.mywebsite.com/mycontent.html (which you have no control over) and that content has an iFrame that you want to manipulate and serve from your own site?

Comment: I have limited control of mycontent.html but enough to write in a javascript, to try to explain it is that www.mywebsite.com/mycontent.html has an iframe on that page, when i click on the link to www.mywebsite.com/mycontent.html i need to change the content of the iframe (not the original source on that page)